# Modal not displaying after successful HTTP Post request

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to display a custom modal component to show after a sucessful `post` request in `onSubmit()` but it will not show up. Before making the `post` request I validate the answers and if they are invalid the modal pops up fine. What am I doing wrong?

Component

```
function ReorderingScreen(props) {

    let ModalView: AlertModal | null = null;

    const [answers, setAnswers] = useState([]);
    const [modelOptions, setModelOptions] = useState({message: '', isSuccess: false});

    const validateAnswers = () => {
        return answers && answers.length && answers.filter(x => x.number && x.number > 0).length > 0;
    }

    const onSubmit = () => {

        if ( !validateAnswers()) {
            setModelOptions({message: "Invalid entry", isSuccess: false })
            ModalView.setModalVisible(true); // modal pop ups fine
            return;
        }

        ProductService.reorder(answers)
            .then(function (response) {
                setModelOptions({message: "Order Submitted", isSuccess: true });
                ModalView.setModalVisible(true); // modal does not pop up 
            });
    }

    return (
        <View>
            <StickyBottomView
                buttons={[{
                    title: "Submit",
                    onPress: () => { onSubmit() }
                }]}
            />
            <AlertModal
                ref={(ref) => ModalView = ref}
                isSuccess={modelOptions.isSuccess}
                message={modelOptions.message}
                clickOutsideToDismiss={true}
                onDismiss={() => {
                    ModalView.setModalVisible(false);
                }}
                buttons={[
                    {
                        title: "Ok",
                        onPress: () => { ModalView.setModalVisible(false) }
                    }
                ]}
        />
        </View>
    )
}
```

AlertModal

```
export default class AlertModal extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        isSuccess: PropTypes.bool,
        title: PropTypes.string,
        message: PropTypes.string,
        buttons: PropTypes.array,
        onDismiss: PropTypes.func,
        clickOutsideToDismiss: PropTypes.bool,
    }

    static defaultProps = {
        isSuccess: false,
        message: 'Unknown Error',
        buttons: [],
        onDismiss: () => {},
        clickOutsideToDismiss: false,
    }

    setModalVisible(visible) {
        this.ModalView.setModalVisible(visible)
    }

    renderButton = (button) => {
        return (
            <PrimaryButton
                title={button.title}
                style={{ width: '100%', marginBottom: StyleConstants.margin.none }}
                onPress={button.onPress}
                isColorReversed={button.isColorReversed}
                isWarningColor={button.isWarningColor}
            />
        )
    }

    renderTitle = () => {
        return (
            <Text style={{...ComponentStyles.Text.phaseTitle, marginBottom: StyleConstants.margin.small}}>{this.props.title}</Text>
        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ModalView
                ref={(ref) => this.ModalView = ref}
                onDismiss={this.props.onDismiss}
                clickOutsideToDismiss={this.props.clickOutsideToDismiss}
            >
                <View style={{ padding: StyleConstants.margin.small }}>
                    <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
                        <Image style={{width: 54, height: 50, marginBottom: StyleConstants.margin.medium }} source={this.props.isSuccess ? require('@Images/okay-status-ic.png') : require('@Images/warning.png')} resizeMode='contain' />
                        { this.props.title && this.renderTitle() }
                        <Text style={{ fontSize: StyleConstants.fontSize.small, fontFamily: StyleConstants.font.regular, textAlign: 'center'}}>{ this.props.message }</Text>
                        { this.props.buttons.map(button => {
                            return this.renderButton(button)
                        }) }
                    </View>
                </View>
            </ModalView>
        );
    }

}
```

ProductService

```
export default class ProductService extends AbstractService {

    static reorder() {
        return this.post(Config.endpoints.reorder, answers);
    }
}
```

AbstractService

```
class AbstractService {

    static post(url, data, queryParams) {
        return this.request({
            method: 'post',
            url,
            data: data,
            queryParams
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution I have to use `useRef`

```
    const onSubmit = () => {
        ProductService.reorder(answers)
            .then(function (response) {
                setModelOptions({message: "Worked", isSuccess: true })
                ModalView.current.setModalVisible(true);
            })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ModalView
                ref={ModalView}
                onDismiss={this.props.onDismiss}
                clickOutsideToDismiss={this.props.clickOutsideToDismiss}
            >
                <View style={{ padding: StyleConstants.margin.small }}>
                    <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
                        <Image style={{width: 54, height: 50, marginBottom: StyleConstants.margin.medium }} source={this.props.isSuccess ? require('@Images/okay-status-ic.png') : require('@Images/warning.png')} resizeMode='contain' />
                        { this.props.title && this.renderTitle() }
                        <Text style={{ fontSize: StyleConstants.fontSize.small, fontFamily: StyleConstants.font.regular, textAlign: 'center'}}>{ this.props.message }</Text>
                        { this.props.buttons.map(button => {
                            return this.renderButton(button)
                        }) }
                    </View>
                </View>
            </ModalView>
        );
    }
```